# Why API Gateway custom domain creation does not supported in cloud formation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I am building cloud formation template to create API gateway with custom domain name. But I can't find documentation for custom domain names in cloudformation. Is cloud formation support custom domain if yes, could anyone please let me know how to create custom domain name resource using cloudformation

Comment: We are working on getting Cloudformation support added for Custom Domain Names. It should be available in a few weeks, please stay tuned.

Answer (score 4):

It is now supported to do a custom domain via cloud formation!

See here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-domainname.html

The problem is it will deploy a cloudfront distribution which could take more than 20 minutes. Use this CFN resource to do it.

```
AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we don't support the domain name resource yet. We are actively working on supporting this.

Until api gateway has released a domain name resource in cloudformation, you can either write a cloudformation custom resource in lambda or use a custom resource library like https://github.com/jed/cfn-api-gateway-custom-domain